# Deploying tensorflow model to GCP without docker

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving

I want to deploy my existing Tensorflow model to Google Cloud Platform. I have an image detection model and I want to make a Python app that will have real time detection.

All tutorials that I found were using Docker. Is it possible to deploy Tensorflow model to server without Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to deploy your Tensorflow model to either:

- [Cloud Functions Python 3.7 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime)
- [App Engine Python 3.7 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime)

neither of which require Docker.

Or, if you don't want to build an application around your model, you could also deploy it to [Cloud ML Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models).

Comment: Thanks for the help. If u can provide a few links to some tutorials, that would be awesome.

Comment: Added some links. Please accept the answer if this resolves your question.